# Wget, preventing session log out

Tags: wget

I'm trying to crawl a website which needs to be logged in with wget but it stops everytime it finds a logout url (https://example.com/logout/).
I've tried excluding the directories but without success.
This is my command:

`wget --content-disposition --header "Cookie: session_cookies" -k -m -r -E -p --level=inf --retry-connrefused -D site.com -X */logout/*,*/settings/* -o log.txt https://example.com/`

I've tried with -R option instead of -X but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Can be solved by the keyword "--reject-regex", like this: "--reject-regex logout", see:[wget-devTips](https://github.com/mythkiven/mkPlan/blob/master/devTips/wget.md)